# Implementing multiple IEnumerables in C#

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a generic class, `Class<T>`, that implements `IEnumerable<T>`. `T` is also constrained to implement `IConvertable`.

I also want this class to be able to pretend to be a string-like object, so I want to implement `IEnumerable<char>`. However, `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable<char>` collide -- what happens if `T` is `char`?

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

EDIT: Here's some clarification -- I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    for (var i = _offset; i < _offset + _length; i++)
        yield return _array[i];
}

public IEnumerator<char> GetEnumerator()
{
    for (var i = _offset; i < _offset + _length; i++)
        yield return _array[i].ToChar(null);
}
```

Comment: did you try to implement just IEnumerable<T> and check if T is char inside the implementation? would this work?

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/334054/cs0695-even-when-types-are-known-to-not-be-the-same

Comment: Whats the other usages of this class? to make it generic?

Comment: As I can see you have GetEnumerator method, which is differ in act with char, there is no need create such a class for example you can have a list<T> which implements all above, I'm saying what is the thing your class wants to implement to create it, and if there is reason to create your class, why you decide create it generic?

Comment: @Saeed: I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: Ok and I can't understand what you wanna to do, I'm saying why you want create a class and If a reason to do it why you decide make it generic, If you can't understand may be because of my bad explanation. no need to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that you need your class to "pretend to be a string-like object". Can you make the string-like behaviour more explicit and avoid implementing `IEnumerable<char>` at all?

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    for (var i = _offset; i < _offset + _length; i++)
        yield return _array[i];
}

// either
public IEnumerator<char> GetCharEnumerator()
{
    for (var i = _offset; i < _offset + _length; i++)
        yield return _array[i].ToChar(null);
}

// or
public IEnumerable<char> AsCharSequence()
{
    for (var i = _offset; i < _offset + _length; i++)
        yield return _array[i].ToChar(null);
}
```

Comment: Woah, wait a second... you can use `yield` to return `IEnumerable` as well as `IEnumerator`?

Answer (score 10):

> Does anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Declaration of generic types such that the base types can unify under construction is sometimes illegal and almost always a bad idea. Avoid, avoid, avoid.

My advice: if you want an object that acts like a string then either override ToString(), or declare an explicit (or, I suppose, implicit) conversion to string. If the user wants a sequence of chars then they can obtain one from the string.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the new object generation from producing a string. I just need to have string-like behavior.

Comment: what about implicit operators?

Comment: Implicit or explicit, there's still a new object.

Comment: @David: And so you're using IEnumerable<char> to avoid creating a new object? How do you plan on avoiding creating an object for the IEnumerator when the sequence of chars (or T's) is enumerated?

Comment: @David: OK, great. So you've decided that "being like a string" is worth pooling one IEnumerator<char> object. Why is "being like a string" not worth eliminating the pooled IEnumerator<char> object and instead pooling *the string*? (And of course I note that you are probably also allocating memory for *the pool*.)

Comment: Enumerators are given back once they're done -- `Dispose` is called. Strings are immutable so they can't be pooled.

Comment: @David: If your strings are long enough that holding the complete string in memory rather than grabbing it one character at a time makes a difference, I'd be more apt to use a `Stream` than an `IEnumerable<char>`.  As for the `Enumerator` being given back, the fact that `Dispose` was called does not mean the memory allocated by the iterator is immediately freed by the garbage collector.

Comment: @Brian: I think what David is getting at is that his pooling strategy is that when the enumerator object is disposed, then it can be "reset" and stuffed back into the pool. It's a slightly scary but reasonably common technique for avoiding memory allocations if you are in an environment where you are highly sensitive to GC pressure. Which it sounds like he is.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class myClass<T>() : IEnuerable<T> where T: IConvertable
{
 public override string ToString()
 {
  if(typeof(T).Equals(typeof(char)))
   return this.Select(obj => obj.ToChar(null).ToString()).Aggregate((cur, nex) => cur + "," + nex);;
  else
   return this.Select(obj => obj.ToString()).Aggregate((cur, nex) => cur + "," + nex);
 }
}
```

or u could just use extension method

```
public static class extension
{
 public static string To_String<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data) where T:IConvertable
 {
  if(typeof(T).Equals(typeof(char)))
   return data.Select(obj => obj.ToChar(null).ToString()).Aggregate((cur, nex) => cur + "," + nex);;
  else
   return data.Select(obj => obj.ToString()).Aggregate((cur, nex) => cur + "," + nex);
 }
}
```

or just put if

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
  if(typeof(T).Equals(typeof(char)))
    for (var i = _offset; i < _offset + _length; i++)
        yield return _array[i].ToChar(null);
  else
    for (var i = _offset; i < _offset + _length; i++)
        yield return _array[i];
}
```