# Invoke multiple generic interface methods on a class through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

***WARNING:*** **While the accepted answer is correct, to anyone attempting to implement this, please see @CodesInChaos's comments as well. This was a bad idea on my part.**

---

I have a generic interface and a class that implements the interface 'n' number of times:

```
interface IA<T>
{
    T Foo();
}

class Baz1 { }
class Baz2 { }

class Bar : IA<Baz1>, IA<Baz2>
{
    Baz1 Foo() { return new Baz1(); }
    Baz2 Foo() { return new Baz2(); }
}
```

How can I use reflection to call both `Foo` methods on an instance of `Bar`?

I already have the following code to get the interface definitions and the generic type parameters:

```
class Frobber
{
    void Frob(object frobbee)
    {
        var interfaces = frobbee.GetType()
            .GetInterfaces()
            .Where(i => i.IsGenericType &&
                i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IA<>).GetGenericTypeDefinition());
    }
}
```

Comment: In my specific situation, instead of `IA<T>`, I have a `Bar` class that implements `IObservable<Baz1>`, `IObservable<Baz2>`, etc. - and also `IObserver<Baz1>`, `IObserver<Baz2>`, etc. - but I didn't want to cloud the discussion. Maybe that's relevant though?

Comment: Okay, thinking about this now, that *is* actually relevant, because the `IObservable<T>` use case (calling two different `Subscribe()` methods on `Baz`) is different from the `IObserver<T>` use case (calling two different `Subscribe()` methods with `Baz` as an argument). So let's just consider the former, as in the example code I've provided.

Comment: Are you sure you want inheritance instead of composition here?

Comment: Good question! I thought about composition but in this particular case I chose inheritance intentionally.

Comment: Then I'll be direct. You shouldn't do that. `IObservable<out T>` is covariant. So if you implement it for different `T`s, returning a different sequence, you won't get a correct implementation for `IObservable<object>`.

Comment: I see your point. :) Thank you.

Comment: Similar questions about implementing two separate versions of `IEnumerable<T>`: 1) [A Class with multiple `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces on it - What to do with the non-generic method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851014/a-class-with-multiple-ienumerablet-interfaces-on-it-what-to-do-with-the-non) 2) [Implementing multiple IEnumerables in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196621/implementing-multiple-ienumerables-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Indeed. The problem is that I had been thinking about the problem in the wrong terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitions:

```
interface IA<T>
{
    T Foo();
}

class Baz1 { }
class Baz2 { }

class Bar : IA<Baz1>, IA<Baz2>
{
    Baz2 IA<Baz2>.Foo()
    {
        return new Baz2(); 
    }

    Baz1 IA<Baz1>.Foo()
    {
        return new Baz1(); 
    }
}
```

Code:

```
    Bar b = new Bar();
    var methods = typeof(Bar).GetInterfaces().Where(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IA<>)).Select(i => i.GetMethod("Foo"));
    foreach(var method in methods)
    {
        var invoked = method.Invoke(b, null); // or add params instead of null when needed
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about having to make the implementations explicit.

Comment: Note you should only be getting one or zero elements in `methods`, so `Select` might need to be replaced with a more appropriate `FirstOrDefault` + check.

Comment: @YoryeNathan you can get more than one `MethodInfo` objects and you will. You can not use FirstOrDefault it beats the puropse.

Comment: Multiple implementations of an explicit interface method, by the same class? How

Comment: If the method is overloaded, you are correct. But in case the method is known to have only one signature, I'd go with `FirstOrDefault`